# htaccess in folder to act like root

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a website and it have many folders. In one folder named **`poster`** and i want that if there is any HTML file which has css link like this `/css/style.css` to `/poster/css/style.css`. Is it possible to do this with .htaccess?

This folder should act like root for inside content.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as your first rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(css/.+)$ /poster/$1
```

Comment: This will all css file will search in poster. right?

Comment: Yes anything starting with `/css` will be redirected to `/poster`